# Firefox Marketplace app licenses

Tags: licensing, firefox-os, marketplace

I ordered a FirefoxOS smartphone yesterday and inspected the Firefox marketplace for apps.

I was wondering where i can find the licenses for each APP.

Is there a standard license (MIT, BSD, GPL)?

I also searched the MDN but i found no information about licensing models.
Neither open, nor closed source.

For example at F-Droid (which i used in past for Android) [solitaire](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=solitair&fdid=com.kmagic.solitaire) the license is Apache2.

The [solitaire at firefox' marketplace](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/pasjanssolitaire) has which license?

Only "Open Web Apps" are [mentioned here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Introduction) but nothing in detail about licensing.

Does anyone knows about?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Comment: Where to ask to be on-topic?

Comment: I don't believe this would be on-topic anywhere on StackExchange. Chances are each app gets to pick its own license, and that most will be entirely proprietary.

Comment: Its sure possible that they are all with different license, but the question is about how to find out which one it is.

There is no information about Licensing at all, even in the manifest files or at the boilerpalte webapp at github:https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App.

So for me it states out that they are all "un-licensed".

Comment: If an app doesn't include a license in its source code or UI, you have no rights to its source. You'd want to contact the developer for clarification.

Comment: So i will contact each developer before installing any app? Sounds funny!

Comment: Don't be intentionally dense. Their putting it on the store is a clear intent to permit you to use the application. Many apps will include a EULA as part of the app. MIT/BSD/GPL licenses affect what you're allowed to do with the source code itself. Without an explicit license, all the default restrictions of copyright law in your jurisdiction apply.

Comment: Response to the on hold message: now i know what on topic means (about programming) so its truly off-topic. I found the right place where this qustion is "on-topic"(see my answer). Do with it as you wish!

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this in the [SUMO forums at mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/1036753#answer-666536) and got my answer:

> It appears that this feature is not available. To find the licensing
>   type of specific applications, you should contact the developer
>   directly.
>
> This tracking bug has more information, including discussions on this
>   feature:
>
> ```
> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=805073
> ```